# How to route traffic from VPC to another by following set of constraints in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cisco, amazon-vpc

Here I have the scenario shown in the figure below, in which there are 3 VPCs. Each VPC hosts 1 VM and CSR 1000v, except VPC2 where there is only CSR. CSRs of both VPCs are able to communicate with each other over preconfigured GRE tunnel.

Let's say we have traffic coming out from another VPC, that traffic requires to pass through VM1 in VPC1 then VM2 in VPC3. The traffic has to pass first from the VM1, then it is routed to CSR1 (Communication within VPC). After that, using the GRE tunnel, it is routed to CSR2 in VPC2, and from there, it is sent to VM2 and finally to CSR3 in VPC3.

I cannot find a way to route the upcoming traffic from a VPC to another as I described above.

[image]
For more details.

Suppose we have traffic that requires to pass the following instances {VM1, VM3 then VM2} and it ends at CSR3. In VPC1, CSR1 receives the traffic from VM1, then it is sent (LINK 2) to CSR2 via GRE tunnel 1. CSR2 itself sends it (LINK 3) to CSR3 via GRE 2. From CSR3 the traffic (LINK 4) is sent to VM3 in VPC4 via GRE 3, then VM3 itself sends it (LINK 5) to CSR4, which will be sent it back to VM2 (LINK 6) via GRE 3. Finally, VM2 forwards the traffic (LINK 7) to its final destination CSR3. If we can see, the GRE tunnel 3 has been passed twice, and it exactly what to achieve, that the tunnels are being passed multiple times.

[image]

Comment: Are your GRE tunnels going over the Internet?  Otherwise AWS does not allow transitive VPCs.

Comment: Most of this is not transit traffic, because it's encapsulated inside GRE, point-to-point, so the peering connections are not a problem.  What doesn't make sense here is the link designated "3".  Why doesn't CSR2 have a tunnel to CSR3 instead of a connection (?) to VM2?  That looks like transit traffic and will not work unencapsulated.

Comment: @RonTrunk yes, the tunnels are going over the internet.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot actually there is GRE tunnel between CSR2 and CSR3 . I may have given a wrong exxample. I modified the post content because there is not enough space in comment input.